# freezed header width is changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code for freezing the header on top:

```
var div = $('#header1');
         var start = $("#header1").offset().top;
         $.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
         var p = $(window).scrollTop();
         $("#header1").css('position',((p)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
         $("#header1").css('top',((p)>start) ? '0px' : '');

         });
```

where `header1` is the id of `thead` but as soon as header starts freezing at top while scrolling, its width changes and also of table's first column

HTML code:

```
    <table id="mytable" summary="Contains" class="table-stripes timetable-stops-table">
            <thead id="header1" width="100%">
                <tr scope="colgroup" colspan="1">
                    <th>1<a class="js-toggle-all-stops">+ show all stops</a></th> 
                    <th >2<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th>3<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span>th>
                    <th >4<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >5<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span>th>
                    <th >6<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >7<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >8<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span>
                                                <span class="alert-icon"><img src="inverted.png" alt="Alert message" class="js-alert-icon"><span class="alert-icon message js-alert"><span class="indicator"></span>Delays</span></span>
                    </th>
                    <th >9<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >10<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >11<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >12<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >13<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >14<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >15<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >16<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >17<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >18<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >19<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >20<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >21<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >22<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >23<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >24<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >25<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >26<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >27<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >28<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                    <th >29<span class="visuallyhidden">Depart</span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="stop-odd">
                <tr class="stop stop-major stop-major-odd js-stop-major">
                    <th>
                        <span class="stop-name">Ocean Road</span>,
                        <span class="stop-loc">Beach</span>
                        <div class="stop-wrap">
                            <span class="stop-no">Stop no<br><a href="#">210825</a></span>
                            <span class="stop-expand"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="js-toggle-stops">+ 1 stop</a></span>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <td>…</td>
                    <td>…</td>
                    <td>…</td>
                    <td>…</td>
                    <td>11:05 <span class="alert-icon"><img src="icon-alert.png" alt="Alert message" class="js-alert-icon"><span class="alert-icon message js-alert"><span class="indicator"></span>Delays</span></span></td>
                    <td>…</td>
                    <td>11:07</td>
                    <td>11:09</td>
                    <td>11:12</td>
                    <td>11:35</td>
                    <td>11:47</td>
                    <td class="next-day">00:05</td>
                    <td class="next-day">00:07 <span class="alert-icon"><img src="alert.png" alt="Alert message" class="js-alert-icon"><span class="alert-icon message js-alert"><span class="indicator"></span>Delays</span></span></td>
                    <td>…</td>
                    <td>06:09</td>
                    <td>11:12</td>
                    <td>11:35</td>
                    <td>11:47</td>
                    <td>11:07</td>
                    <td>11:09</td>
                    <td>11:12</td>
                    <td>11:35</td>
                    <td>11:47</td>
                    <td>11:07</td>
                    <td>11:09</td>
                    <td>11:12</td>
                    <td>06:35</td>
                    <td>11:47</td>
                </tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show your css and html? or just create jsFiddle example.

Comment: Which browser are you using. Can you provide an example code with html?

Comment: i have added html code

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use 2 different tables: one with header, other with body. And you should to  set same width to corresponding cells of tables.

I tryed to reproduce your problem and all is working: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3uUxz/1/)

Comment: thanks it is working now... but header is showing after the table end also..Can you suggest a way to solve this

Comment: What do u mean 'after the table'? Is this the answer [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3uUxz/3/) ?

Comment: The header should be visible till the content of table scrolled. After table gets scrolled completely from top to bottom, header should disappears